# О Windows и низкоуровневым взаимодействием с сетями

Tags: c, windows, сеть

у меня два вопроса:

1) Можно ли как-то писать драйвера под Windows без WDK/DDK? Сложно это не сложно - меня не волнует, мне хочется узнать как работают драйвера изнутри.

2) Как можно искуственно создать входящий пакет в Виндоус? То есть, программно создать такую ситуацию, будто пакет пришёл откуда-то из сети, и что-бы этот пакет можно было редактировать на уровне IP.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы лучше задавать по отдельности.

Answer (score 1):

Драйвера некоторых устройств, которые имеют стандартные интерфейсы (например usb, com) можно реализовать без DDK.

Для такой ручной сборки очень подойдет `tun` `tap` драйвер от Опенвпн. С одной стороны файлоподобный интерфейс, со стороны виндовс - сетевая карточка. [Пример скрипта сборки пакета вручную.](https://openwsn.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OW/pages/5963834/Python+script)

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет, без WDK/DDK нельзя.
2. Тут нужно делать виртуальный сетевой интерфейс-заглушку, под Windows так называемый драйвер минипорта [NDIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/ndis-driver-stack). Но это для пользователя будет выглядеть как отдельное сетевое подключение. Если же нужно "вклиниваться" в существующее подключение, то можно сделать [фильтрующий драйвер](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/introduction-to-ndis-filter-drivers) NDIS.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Исправил

Comment: Драйвер можно написать без ddk) или вы не установливали драйвера на коврик от мышки в 2000ых? Можно соорудить и чтото посложнее.

Comment: @eri Примеры у вас есть?

Comment: Зависит от устройства..

Comment: На усб есть группа каналов вход-выход. В диспечер устройств драйвер пишется инф файлом, а дальше цепляй канал и работай с устройством напрямую